# Storing mySQL query results on client side to use for future requests

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

At the moment when logging a user in, I send attributes in a response object. In the javascript I save certain attributes to a variable I need to use for future requests.

E.g. onresponse - `currentUser = req.body.user`
`currentID = req.body.id` etc.

Then say I need to query using the *ID*, I will send this variable in the request.

Is this a viable method of doing this? Im not very concerned about security - just getting a software demo that wont be going online running. Feel like i might be missing a trick here.

Comment: `Im not very concerned about security` and you concerned about quality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use session for this purpose. Where each user can have their own session and you can clear them when they logout. All the details or whatever data for the particular user you need for future you can save them on to session.